# Google Persistent Cloud Anchors in Unity: Error Missing API Key

Tags: c#, firebase, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, arcore

**Issue**:

I am trying to host **persistent** google cloud anchors in Unity. For this, I used the **keyless** authentication and followed all the steps as per google developer guide:
[google developer guide for persistent cloud anchors in Unity][1]

I am using Unity Editor 2020.2.3f1, ARFoundation and Firebase 7.2.0.

But I am still getting the following error:

```
Error ARCore-AnchorServiceClient Error calling CreateAnchor RPC: 
Error ARCore-AnchorServiceClient grd: PERMISSION_DENIED: The request is missing a valid API key.
at grb.i(PG:1)
at hem.c(PG:3)
at guh.run(PG:1)
at guj.e(PG:4)
at guj.c(PG:1)
at gtc.a(PG:3)
at gtv.run(PG:2)
at hav.run(PG:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Is there any way to host persistent cloud anchors with ARFoundation in Unity?
[1]: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/cloud-anchors/developer-guide-android#keyless-authentication